# Discrepancy compiler output for structured-bindings with ref-qualifier in C++17

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, structured-bindings

Consider the snippet below:

```cpp
#include<tuple>

double refd = 5.0;
int refi = 1;
decltype(auto) foo(){return std::tuple<double&,int&>{refd,refi};}

auto&[d,i] = foo(); //msvc:pass, gcc:fail, clang:fail
```

Available on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ZqLp4C)

In the case of gcc/clang, the error is:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type `'std::tuple<double&,int&>&'` to an rvalue of type `'std::tuple<double&, int&>'`

However, MSVC does not complain and compiles just fine.

Which one is correct ?

Comment: Disable extension on MSVC by `/Za` and the code fails too.

Comment: You're doing `auto& x = foo();` Does that help answer your question?

Comment: @rafix07 If you have the time, explain what `/Za` exactly does, and this should be an answer.

Comment: @Barry I closed it to the canonical.

Comment: @NathanOliver Weird. I'm pretty sure that target includes every permutation I searched for but couldn't find it anyway. Nice!

Comment: Prefer `/permissive-` to `/Za` if you can; it makes MSVC even more standards compliant

Comment: @Barry It's a tough one to find.  I actually used it in an answer of mine with the link text containing evil so when I need it I just search my answers for evil and it pops right up :)

Comment: An insight in what's happening: [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGU8dHVwbGU+Cgpkb3VibGUgcmVmZCA9IDUuMDsKaW50IHJlZmkgPSAxOwpkZWNsdHlwZShhdXRvKSBmb28oKXtyZXR1cm4gc3RkOjp0dXBsZTxkb3VibGUmLGludCY+e3JlZmQscmVmaX07fQoKYXV0byYmW2QsaV0gPSBmb28oKTsgLy9tc3ZjOnBhc3M=&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0)